# Haskell. Numbers in binary numbers. words

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Char


blockCode :: S   

lett2num :: Char ->  Int
lett2num y 
   | (or


num2bin :: Int -> [Int]
num2bin n: negative number"
  where n2b 0  =  []
        n2b n  =  n `mod` 2 : n2b (n `div` 2)
```

Comment: If I understand your binary encoding correctly, it will be impossible to decode because it's ambiguous. For example the strings AA and C would both be encoded as 11. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: em..no. I dont want this but I dont know how to do it in another way

Comment: You'll have to pad with zeroes up to some predetermined length (depending on the size of your alphabet).

Comment: @Katja: If you don't want/need this specific encoding, then why don't you just use the result from `ord`?

Comment: @Katja: Also note that when you use `Int`, you won't be able to encode long strings, as `Int` has a maximum size. If you use `Integer` instead you can encode strings of arbitrary length.

Comment: @larsmans sorry? I understood nothing%)

@sepp2k I meant I dont want it to be encoded that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concatMap show` to transform a list into a string:

```
Main> num2bin 8
[0,0,0,1]
Main> concatMap show $ num2bin 8
"0001"
```

but note that your function's output is reversed.

To do everything in one go, do

```
num2bin :: Int -> String
num2bin n
  | n >= 0     =  concatMap show $ reverse $ n2b n
  | otherwise  =  error "num2bin: negative number"
  where n2b 0  =  []
        n2b n  =  n `mod` 2 : n2b (n `div` 2)
```

Comment: I modified it.that it is not reversed anymore
but I need numbers to be out of the list already in a programm. I mean the function num2bin should already containt something that will convert a list of numbers into numbers

Comment: Then rename it and put the `concatMap` in a new function that you call `num2bin`. Or fold the operation into the code, up to you.

Comment: num2bin :: Int->[Int]
num2bin 0 = []
num2bin n
    | n>=0 = concatMap(reverse (n `mod` 2 : (num2bin( n `div` 2))))
do you mean this way?

Answer (score 0):

Function converts integer to binary:

```
num2bin :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> String
num2bin 0 = "0"
num2bin 1 = "1"
num2bin n
    | n < 0         = error "Negative number"
    | otherwise     = num2bin (n `div` 2) ++ show (n `mod` 2)
```