# haskell. words into binary numbers

Tags: haskell

**edited everything**

I need to convert words into binary numbers.
With a bit help of yours I got this

```
 import Data.Char


blCo :: String -> String
blCo xs = concatMap  lett2num) xs            

lett2num :: Char ->  Int
lett2num y 
   | (ord 'A' <= ord y) ord 'z') =  (ord y - ord 'a') +1


num2bin :: Int -> String
num2bin n
  | n >= 0     =  ctive number"
  where n2b 0  =  []
        n2b n  =  n `mod` 2 : n2b (n `div` 2)
```

GHC tells me a mistake.I dont undertsand it
mistake:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Char' against inferred type `String'
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `num2bin (lett2num x)'
In the expression: num2bin (lett2num x) : blCo xs
In the definition of `blCo':
    blCo (x : xs) = num2bin (lett2num x) : blCo xs
```

Comment: What is that `| x:xs` in blCo for? Remove it.

Comment: Can you tell us the error the interpreter gave you? When you go see a doctor, you do tell him what hurts and where, don't you?

Comment: blCo::String -> Int
blCo  x  = num2bin(lett2num x)
shoud it be so?

Comment: Why did you change the input of `lett2num` to be a `String`?  It should be `char`, definitely - was this an attempt to "fix" the compiler message?  It's not going down the right track, if so.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. It should haave been a continuation of the first:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682705/haskell-numbers-in-binary-numbers-words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few type errors here, from just a cursory glance.

You've declared `blCo` as `String -> Integer`.  So it takes a string, and returns an integer.  But the String argument, `x`, is passed into `lett2num` which is supposed to take an character - this isn't going to work, and that's what the error message means.  Perhaps you meant to declare the line as

```
blCo [x]  = num2bin(lett2num x)
```

so that `x` would match the character value in a one-character string?  **In any case, that's what's causing the compiler error** - you're passing a `String` into a function that expects a `char`.

Additionally, `blCo` is supposed to return an `Integer`, but its return value overall is going to be the output of `num2bin` (with *some* argument) - and this function returns a `String`, so this can never work either.  Without seeing what `lett2bin` does (and/or what your approach is), I can't say what's wrong - but it seems that something, somewhere doesn't add up.

So what's it to be - are you trying to output a String (the binary representation of a number-string passed in)?  Or are you trying to output an integer of some kind?

Comment: There is no such thing as a lett2num in the code. There is a num2lett that does take an Int, but no lett2num.

Comment: if I got you right.
I need to write
 blCo :: String -> String
blCo (x:xs)   = num2bin(lett2num x):blCo xs
num2bin :: Int -> String

Answer (score 0):

1) Please write clearer questions including the compiler error, if there is one.

2) Please include all your code, when possible.  This code is missing lett2num.

3) Some issues:

You need to import `Data.Char` to get the `ord` and `chr` functions:

```
import Data.Char
```

Your guard on blCo is nonsensical, remove it.  Also, that second definition will never run because the first one always matches, that is in `blCo x`  the `x` will always match the input.  So you need to rewrite blCo.

EDIT:
There's still a bit wrong here.  I suggest you go on IRC and talk it out in real time so you get more understanding in addition to correct code.

1) The typing for starters: you call a function (`num2bin`) that is supposed to return a `String` and concatenate it on a list using `:` which would result in `:: [String]`) but want to end up with only a `String`.  I'm guessing you wanted to use `blCo xs = concatMap (num2bin . lett2num) xs`.

2) `blCo` is recursive on the list but doesn't define what to do when the list hits `[]`.   One option is to redefine it to use `concatMap`, making it non-recursive.

3) You missed part of my point on importing `Data.Char`.  The point is to have the full code on SO so people can copy/paste your code to help you more easily, not just that you needed it on you private copy.

Comment: I edited my post. and I have already import Data.Char. I just dont understand the mistake, I dont understand why I should correct.

Comment: sorry, I dont know what IRC is. 
and.. so. you suggest I better write blCo xs = (concatMap num2bin . lett2num) xs , then I should change as well num2bin :: Int -> [Int]  and num2bin n
  | n >= 0     =  reverse ( n2b n)

Comment: Katja: Oops, see the edit, I messed up and ment `blCo xs = concatMap (num2bin . lett2num) xs`.  This does not require any changes to `num2bin`.  IRC is a chat system (see wikipedia), the [haskell irc channel](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IRC_channel) is popular.

Comment: I saw your mistipp. but it still shows me a mistake. the programm is loaded ok but when i tip 'ABCD' it tells me  lexical error in string/character literal at character 'B'

Comment: If you want a `Char`, type `'A'` (single quotes). If you want a `String`, type `"ABCD"` (double quotes). `'ABCD'` is not a `String` because it uses single quotes, and not a `Char` because it contains more than one letter.